# AMQP protocol from Apex - RabbitMQ

Tags: apex, rest-api, webservices, rest

I am trying to connect and send data to RAbbit MQ messaging protocol. At all places it is provided that we should use AMQP protocol and this is something I am not sure how to do from Apex. Has anyone already worked on using AMQP protocol with Apex?

I already tried using HTTP request and it is giving me Invalid HTTP Response from all ways I tried.

I already tried - https://thysmichels.com/2017/02/17/apex-callout-to-rabbitmq-queue/

Any help would be appreciated.

Regards,
Ray

Comment: I can suggest you to try using curl or postman first, and as soon as you have working request -- move it to apex

Comment: Do you have any reference for same as I could not find any reference on how to create a REST based request for AMQP

Comment: Well AMQP + curl does return this in google -- https://www.cloudamqp.com/docs/http.html